# rest-assured: Format of number change after being retrieved using JsonPath

Tags: java, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am observing that the format or value of an item from a rest-assured response is changed when I try to retrieve the item using JsonPath.

Value of the field is 16637906.26 when I get the `response.asString()`.

However when I retrieve this specific information using JsonPath, it returns the number as 1.6637906E7.

Below is the rest-assured JsonPath I used to get the data:

```
List<Map<String,?>> values = JsonPath.with(actResponse).param(param,value).get("entries.findAll { entries -> entries."+param+" == "+param+" }")
```

where param is a variable pointing to parameter I use.When I print this List, I can see that the value is then displayed as 1.6637906E7. All other smaller values are returned properly.

I tried to play with it a bit like converting the number etc, however nothing seem to work.

Highly appreciate if someone can guide me through this.

Comment: You requesting response to provide value in asString , In this case, It will do exactly what needs to do .

Comment: And I see the proper value when I get the response.asString(). Also the actResponse passed to JosnPath is the exact same response.asString().